# How to give mutiple spaces to an integer to shown on form as a string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to fetch a roll No. of 6 digits lets suppose 690100 from database. i want to show it on form with 3 spaces between digits. How it is possible? After that I also want to split them with spaces to get individual digit.

```
        string rollNo;
        rollNo = dr["RollNo"].ToString();
        char[] arrRollNo = rollNo.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

Comment: *with 3 spaces between digits* what would be the expected output

Comment: If you want the individual digits why you not just divide by 10 and get the mod of 10?

Comment: Expected output would be 6   9   0   1   0   0

Comment: @waqasqureshi In your example - *three* spaces? I see one...

Comment: @waqasqureshi So you want to insert three spaces between **every** digit, remove the spaces by splitting and ignore the additional spaces? Why?

Comment: I typed three spaces it is showing one. Actually there is a design on format of 6 boxes and it doesn't fit my roll no without spaces so what should i do now?

Comment: @waqasqureshi I have **no** idea what that is supposed to mean ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can convert your number to a string, split into characters and join these again with spaces:

```
int i = 690110;
char[] chars = i.ToString().ToCharArray();
// To get a formatted string:
string s = string.Join("   ",chars);
// To get the digits:
int[] digits = chars.Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Did you include the last statement `.ToArray()`?

Comment: THanks Stephan adding toArray worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You could use: `Regex.Replace(num, @"\d", "$0 ").TrimEnd();`